# how to avoid while loop and return in scala

Tags: scala, while-loop

I see in scala it is a bad practice to use both while and return. I have to click on the next page link if it exists. How can I do it without while and return?

```scala
def check = {
  do {
    if (findElements(locator).exists(_.getText.contains(input)))
      return true
  } while (nextPageLocatorInPageExists(nextPageLocator))
  false
}
```

Comment: It would be more important to fix the fact that `locator` is mutable for what I can see. But you may just rewrite this as a simple recursion or using something like `Iterator.unfold(nextPageLocatorInPageExists(nextPageLocator)).exist(locator => findElements(locator).exists(_.getText.contains(input)))`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez -> can you please show the simple recursion method you suggest with this. New to scala. So would like to start with the simple methods.

Comment: Sure, I tried to make a very general explanation [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/RmMPXSkYQ9Ww0BgEQTY5Bw/1)  hope it helps. Also, I would recommend you to pick up the [**tour of Scala**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html) or some book or course to cover all the aspects of Scala gradually. Finally, if you have more questions feel free to contact me through [**gitter**](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) or even better just ask your question in the general room, plenty of helpful people there :)

Comment: SO in effect, you have a sequence of pageLocators, and you want to find the first that matches a condition. I'd probably turn nextPageLocatorInPageExists into an iterator (or a lazily evaluted Seq), then use .exists{}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward recursive solution:

```scala
def check = {
  if (findElements(locator).exists(_.getText.contains(input)))
    true
  else if (! nextPageLocatorInPageExists(nextPageLocator))
    false
  else
    check
}
```

It can be written in a terser way by using `||` and `&&`, but then it wouldn't be tail recursive, and that's pretty much mandatory in a case like this.

Comment: does too! https://scastie.scala-lang.org/J0D1WQZhRyy0vl0tPqrzYw

Comment: That's an interesting observation! Apparently there are some special optimisations for Boolean operators in the Scala compiler.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I'm guessing `nextPageLocatorInPageExists(nextPageLocator)` mutatates `locator`, and that's what drives your while loop.

If that's the case, here are two options:

a do-while loop without return: the closest to what you wrote:

```
def check = {
  var found = false
  do {
    found = findElements(locator).exists(_.getText.contains(input))
  } while (!found && nextPageLocatorInPageExists(nextPageLocator))
  found
}
```

a recursive solution

```
def check: Boolean = findElements(locator).exists(_.getText.contains(input)) ||
                     (nextPageLocatorInPageExists(nextPageLocator) && check)
```